# Visual + DAX: Find sum of total sales for all customers for a location, without including the selected location itself in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

This is my first question in stackoverflow so I hope you forgive me any errors in my problem statement style. Please let me know if and what I can improve for my next question!

I have a fact table 'Sales' that has the columns [sales amount], [customer] and [sales location]:

```
sales amount | customer | sales location |
   €50       |    A     |     beach      |
   €40       |    A     |     mall       |
   €30       |    A     |     office     |
   €20       |    B     |     mall       |
   €35       |    B     |     office     |
   €25       |    C     |     beach      |
   €15       |    C     |     office     |
```

I want to create a measure to create a horizontal bar chart visual that shows *per sales location type*, the total sales of the other sales location types. The caviat is that I only want to show the sales of the customers that also have sales in the selected sales location.

- So for sales location "**beach**", I want to show the sales of customer A and C (who bought at the beach) at the mall and the office, respectively. In total €40 + €15, so €55 in total
- for sales location "**mall**", I want to show the sales of customer A and B (who bought at the mall) at the beach and the office, respectively. In total €50 + €35, so €80 in total
- for sales location "**office**", I want to show the sales of customer A, B and C (who bought at the office) at the beach+mall, mall and beach, respectively. In total €50 + €40 + €20 + €25, so €135 in total

I think I have a working DAX code, but what I want to do is to use the legenda option in the horizontal bar chart to show how much of the other sales originates from which location. In other words, to add [sales location] as a legenda.

```
Beach:  |   €40   |   €45     |
Mall:   |        €80         |  €35   |
Office: |       €75         |     €60      |
```

My problem is that e.g., for beach, the legenda sticks to beach and fills the whole €55 horizontal bar chart with the beach legenda color. Which is logical, as it is the selected value in the visual. However, at beach I want to show the distribution between mall and office.

My DAX code is as follows:

```
Cross sell areas = 
VAR customer_list = SUMMARIZE(FILTER(Sales, 
                                     Sales[sales location]=SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[sales location])), 
                               Sales[customer])

RETURN 
CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[sales amount]),
              Sales[customer] in customer_list, 
              Sales[sales location]<>SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[sales location]))
```

I think this measure works. But the as mentioned, the filter does not work the way I want it to. Do I need to filter on the sales location of the created VAR customer_list, if that is even possible? I don't know how to proceed.

Any help is greatly appreciated in this challenging excercise!

Comment: Are you sure about the outcomes? Shouldn't the result for beach be €85 (30 + 40 + 15)? And for mall €115  (50 + 30 + 35)?

Comment: Hi Marco, you are completely right! Thank you for your sharp eye. I've changed it.